# Z-buffer fighting on iOS OGLES 2

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I've got the following issue on my application:

[image: z-buffer fighting on corners]

When I don't move the viewmatrix, the triangles don't disappear/re-appear.
Note that the greenish and blueish planes are made of many small triangles.
Also, using the same GL commands and shader in **WebGL** works like a charm.

Could it be that the shader creates this issue? The shader does use highprecision floating points, so that shouldn't be an issue, right?

**Edit:** <s>Also, I noticed that the texture map on the top is half as big as it is on WebGL (it's 8x8 tiles in WebGL, and only 4x4 tiles in OGLES 2). Could be an issue on my side...</s> Texture mapping wasn't correctly applied. Weird.

Comment: Are the surfaces coplanar?

Comment: @MarceloCantos No, it's a box with individual planes. The top plane does intersect with the sides, as it is pushed down a bit. Also, the sides are a bit pushed to the inside: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5otb88gdciyfgp0/Screenshot%202013-10-14%2011.22.37.png)

Comment: Then you shouldn't be seeing any Z-fighting. Does each surface render correctly if the others are omitted?

Comment: @MarceloCantos After some testing, it seems that, for some reason, a zNear of 0.01 does not work as it should. Using 1.0 works correctly. Weird. Should I delete this post and start about the other issue instead?

Comment: You can add the new information to the existing question.

Comment: What is your zFar? If there's too great a range, then you'll lose resolution. Also, how many bits does your depth buffer have? That will, obviously, also affect resolution.

Comment: zFar was 100, zNear was 0.01. For some reason, this range wasn't applied...

Comment: 100/0.01 = 10000 is a fairly high ratio. Why this is a problem is difficult to explain in a comment. [This article](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm) in the OpenGL FAQ explains it in some detail.

Comment: But why does 10000/1 works then?

Comment: Probably because it pushes your model closer to the near side, which has better depth resolution. The article explains this. It's a long read, but it'll be worth your while.